# Magento 2 extension for submitting form from front-end and save values to database table

Tags: magento2

I am looking for a module which submits form from front-end and save values in database table.

I searched a lot with google but couldn't find a proper tutorial.
If zip file is available then it is better, because I followed some tutorials.
Please guys help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you q-l-p for correction

Comment: Please anybody can help me into this. Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what type of form/module you're looking for and where do you want to store the values in Database? But, at least you can check this [Checkout Custom Form](https://github.com/sbodak/magento2-checkout-custom-form) Github link. Question is not clear enough so please edit your post and be specific!

Comment: Hello Adeel, I am  new in mangeto 2  that is why i am learning how to create module.  I am loooking a simple custom module where customer submit form and form's field value store in a separate(Module's) table.  Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can fork/download Magento 2 Module directly from this link
[Magento 2 Module - Frontend with Admin Grid](https://github.com/chiragit007/magento2-module-with-frontend-and-admin-grid/tree/master/app/code/Ktpl/Chirag) Github to check how Magento displays and stores data in database table and also you can find `InstallSchema.php` file under `setup` folder which is used to create database table.

You can also follow below tutorials to learn Magento 2:

1. [Grid and Form in Magento 2 Admin Panel (Part 1)](https://www.mage-world.com/blog/grid-and-form-in-magento-2-admin-panel-part-1.html)
2. [Grid and Form in Magento 2 Admin Panel (Part 2)](https://www.mage-world.com/blog/grid-and-form-in-magento-2-admin-panel-part-2.html)

With above two links you could learn how to create Grid and Form in Admin Panel, and the below link shows how to create a page on frontend

[Create the news list page via frontend in Magento 2](https://www.mage-world.com/blog/create-the-news-list-page-via-frontend-in-magento-2.html)

Comment: Thank you Adeel, Let me try these links.  Thank you

Comment: you're welcome, btw it would be great if you start with tutorials than you at least know and understand the flow of Magento 2. Well, if the answer is helpful then please don't forget to upvote/accept :)

Comment: I installed https://github.com/chiragit007/magento2-module-with-frontend-and-admin-grid/tree/master/app/code/Ktpl/Chirag module. But this showing this error while submit form   a:4:{i:0;s:70:"Class Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\AbstractResource does not exist";i:1;s:9734:"#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Ktpl\\Chirag\\Mod...').    Please let me know what i need to do

Comment: First of all, how did you install the above mentioned module (by composer?) and after the installation of module, have you enabled the module and run the setup:upgrade?

Comment: and after installing the module remove var/generation var/di and set permission to var folder by sudo chmod -R 777 var/ and at last run bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: I imstalled by keeping folder manually inside app/code.  My module is enable, i ran setup:upgrade command. I remove all folders from Var folder. Let me try by setting permission to var folder

Comment: also run bin/magento setup:di:compile